# How to change JSON form?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have following json

`{"result": { "a": 1, "b": 2 "c": [ { "d": 3, "e": 4 }, { "d": 3, "e": 4 } ] }}`

I want to change it become like this:

`{"result": [{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 3, "e": 4 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 3, "e": 4 }]}`

is there a way change JSON like this?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Don't change the json string, change the underlying object.

Comment: Sure, you can use a text editor and change it however you like.  But if you want to do it programmatically you'd probably be better off reading the JSON into a data structure and changing the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` for this:

```
var obj = {"result": { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [ { "d": 3, "e": 4 }, { "d": 3, "e": 4 } ] }};

var res = obj.result.c.reduce(function(res, arrObj) {
    res.result.push({a:obj.result.a, b:obj.result.b, d:arrObj.d, e:arrObj.e});
    return res;
}, {result:[]});
```

Or if it should be more dynamic, then like this:

```
var res = obj.result.c.reduce(function(res, arrObj) {
    Object.keys(obj.result).forEach(function(key) {
       if (typeof obj.result[key] !== 'object')
           arrObj[key] = obj.result[key];
    });
    res.result.push(arrObj);
    return res;
}, {result:[]});
```